# moz-column is not working in firefox

Tags: css

I am trying to create a four column grid using the following code. The code is working perfectly in Chrome but its not creating the columns in firefox.

You can check the following code live here: http://jsfiddle.net/rfTXX/1/

I have checked this tutorial http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/ and I think my codes are okay, but still its not working in firefox.

Could you please tell me how to fix the css so that it works in almost in every browser?

CSS

```
#wrapper {
width: 90%;
max-width: 1100px;
min-width: 800px;
margin: 50px auto;
}

#columns {
-webkit-column-count: 4;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
-webkit-column-fill: auto;
-moz-column-count: 4;
-moz-column-gap: 10px;
-moz-column-fill: auto;
column-count: 4;
column-gap: 15px;
column-fill: auto;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="columns">

    <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" />
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, 
            ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
            Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" />
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, 
            ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
            Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
        </p>
    </div>


    <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" />
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, 
            ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
            Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
        </p>
    </div>

       <div class="pin">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" />
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Sed feugiat consectetur pellentesque. Nam ac elit risus, 
            ac blandit dui. Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
            Duis rutrum porta tortor ut convallis.
        </p>
    </div>

 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try without the `column-fill` property, it should work.

Or use `-moz-column-fill: balance;` instead.

Comment: Thanks its working. I had to remove `-moz-column-fill: auto;` to make it work. But without the `-moz-column-fill: auto;` it does not create any space between each grids.

Comment: Use `-moz-column-fill: balance;` instead of `-moz-column-fill: auto;` to make it work on Firefox. It works for me !

Answer (score 1):

Just to be on the safe side include `-moz-column-count:"your value"` in css 
and include a java script `document.getElementById("lstAccessList").style.MozColumnCount = "your value";`
Trust me this worked for me after an exhaustive search.

Answer (score 0):

The -moz-column-rule property is supported in Firefox from version 3.5.
http://help.dottoro.com/lcqjxgjq.php

Comment: I am using the latest version of Firefox but its still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

remove column-fill and add `-moz-columns:4;`
it's work for me

Answer (score -1):

Use `-moz-column-fill:balance` instead of `-moz-column-fill:auto`

Don't ask me why but it works for me!